# Angular: Running ngcc causing performance issues in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular10, angular-language-service

In my Visual Studio Code editor after last updates I see this text in the status bar:

[image]

`Angular: Running ngcc for project d:/..../tsconfig.spec.json`

It looks like frozen or do nothing a while, just spin the arrows.

Before this text I saw a similar one with `tscfonfig.json` ending...

Since this text is showing in the status my vscode has some performance issues... it became very-very slow. Sometimes, very often the quick import (ctrl-space) isn't work, not found classes, interfaces what before this update worked well.

What is this? Is it neccessary or can I switch off somehow? Is this maybe a plugin bug?

Comment: Having the same problem, I dont think this is caused due to extensions, but rather because of a solution style tsconfig..

Comment: Is this related to VSCode or do you encounter this issues in your terminal, too? There was a time when transpiling on Windows was unbelievable slow. It was faster to boot a Linux in VirtualBox and transpile on Linux. It could be related to that.

Comment: Related to VSCode. Other applications on Windows running well. Otherwise the `ng build --watch` is running well too. Only in the VSCode happening something wierd...

Comment: Same here, makes VSCode unusable with quite a large angular repo. Had to switch IDEs to maintain my sanity

Comment: I'm having the same trouble:

VSCode: 1.53.2
Angular Language Service: 11.2.2
"@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.2",
"@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",

Comment: In my case it was the new `experimental-ivy` feature from Angular Language Service extension. I posted an answer on how to disable it.

Comment: Update the Angular Language Service Extension to V11.2.3. They have resolved the performance issue now. See here: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases/tag/v11.2.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:** They improved performance in Angular Language Service v11.2.3 release. In this version (or higher), you can re-enable `Experimental-ivy` feature, it's still slower but not as before, now at least it's usable (they said there is room for improvement).

---

If it got slow again, it's likely a known issue with the new `Experimental-ivy` feature from the Angular Language Service, they are [working on a fix](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1104).

For now, you can temporarily disable it by opening the extension settings:

[image: Manage Extensions UI]

Then uncheck the **Experimental-ivy** feature:

[image: Disable ivy]

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I had to turn off [FullTemplateTypeCheck](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) in the Angular Compiler Options.

Note: this issue has been resolved in version V11.2.3 of the Angular Language Service VS Code extension.

If you want to disable fullTemplateTypeCheck:

In your tsconfig.json file set "fullTemplateTypeCheck" to false and **restart** VS Code.

fullTemplateTypeCheck is in the angularCompilerOptions object in your tsconfig.json file.

Here is mine:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false    
  }
```

> Update
>
> If you upgrade the Angular Language Service VS Code Extension to
> V11.2.3. It looks like this problem has been resolved. See [here](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases/tag/v11.2.3).
>
> I updated the extension to  V11.2.3 and I have re-enabled fullTemplateTypeCheck and I can confirm it is working as expected.